# ReactNative FlatList space between items is always white in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a pretty regular vertical FlatList, nothing special, however I found some weird styling bug: the background color of the list itself is always white, which makes my list items (which also has a white background) indistinguishable. Is there any way to fix it?
My code:

```
<FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={{
      backgroundColor:'purple',
    }}
    ListHeaderComponent={
      <HeaderView />
    }
    data={places}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <PlaceListItem place={item} navigation={navigation} />
    )}
/>
```

And PlaceListItem:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 15,
        borderColor: 'white',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginBottom: 10,
    },
    infoContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        paddingStart: 10,
    },
    image: {/*just size*/},
    title: {/*just font style*/},
    item: {/*just font style*/},
})
<SelectionHighlight
    onPress={() => doStuff()}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.image}
        source={{
          uri: photo,
        }}
      />
      <View style={styles.infoContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.item}>{address}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </SelectionHighlight>
```

And results are:

> Android

[image: Android - space between items has proper color, as set in <code>contentContainerStyle</code>]

> iOS

[image: iOS - space between items is white]

Comment: What if you put your flatList into View and set the backgroundColor there?

Comment: @Konstantin nope, still the same

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it turns out to be mine own mistake. I set `backgroundColor:'white'` to the `TouchableHighlight`, and for some reason it works fine on Android, but gives this result on iOS. Setting `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` to `TouchableHighlight` solved the issue.